# Как посчитать количество символа в каждом отрезке текста на python?

Tags: python, строки, символы, замена

У меня есть файл с текстом, отрывок приведен ниже. В нем надо заменить все строки, начинающиеся с '>' на '!'(или любой другой символ кроме буквенного, не принципиально какой). Т.е. вся строка, идущая после знака '>' должна быть удалена и заменена на '!'.  Затем в каждом таком отрезке, который сейчас разграничивается символом '>' и будет заменен на '!', нужно посчитать число определенных букв в процентах, например 'A' и 'S', и эти данные записать в новый файл. На данный момент знаю только, как полностью удалить все строки с символом('>'), но не знаю, как их заменить на другой символ. Сам файл по ссылке https://ru.files.fm/u/kfkrat27.
П.С. возможно есть другой способ посчитать нужные символы в отрезке без замены '>' на '!' или другой знак. Но в любом случае нужно посчитать нужные символы в  каждом буквенном отрезке. Например, в первом отрезке (MVE...AKA) посчитать процент встречаемости символов 'A' и 'S'. Результат должен быть примерно таким (цифры просто придумал): 1 отрезок: A - 6.53%, S - 3.22%. 2  отрезок: A- 8.98%, S - 5.61%, 3 отрезок: A - 3.1%, S - 7.4% и т.д. для каждого отрезка
Пример файла:

```
>sp|P00321|FLAV_MEGEL Flavodoxin OS=Megasphaera elsdenii OX=907 PE=1 SV=1
MVEIVYWSGTGNTEAMANEIEAAVKAAGADVESVRFEDTNVDDVASKDVILLGCPAMGSE
ELEDSVVEPFFTDLAPKLKGKKVGLFGSYGWGSGEWMDAWKQRTEDTGATVIGTAIVNEM
PDNAPECKELGEAAAKA
>sp|P23160|R34K_CLOPA 34.2 kDa protein in rubredoxin operon OS=Clostridium     pasteurianum OX=1501 PE=3 SV=1
MKEEKQLDLVIIGAGPAGLTAAIYAIRAKLNTLVLENELVGGQIRETYTVENFPGFNVIS
GADLADKMEEHAASIGVNIDQFSNIEKIKLSDDEKIIETEDVIYKVKALIIATGAKSRRL
PIPEEEKLHGKVIHYCELCDGALYQGKDLVVVGGGNSAVEAAIFLTKYARNITIVHQFDY
LQAQKYSQDELFKHKNVKIIWDSEIRNIVGENEIEKIVVENVKTKQKTELKADGVFVYIG
YEPKTELFKDSININKWGYIETDENMETNIKGVFAAGDVRSKLIRQLTTAVSDGTVAALM
AEKYIGGK
>sp|P05385|DBH_CLOPA DNA-binding protein HU OS=Clostridium pasteurianum     OX=1501 GN=hup PE=1 SV=1
MNKAELITSMAEKSKLTKKDAELALKALIESVEEALEKGEKVQLVGFGTFETRERAAREG
RNPRTKEVINIPATTVPVFKAGKEFKDKVNK
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы предоставить файл с исходными данными в текстовом виде, а не в виде фото? и показать пример, что на что нужно поменять, потому что из объяснения это не очень понятно.

Comment: Отредактировал, добавив ссылку на файл и уточнив описание

Comment: добавил еще одно уточнение, надеюсь  так немного понятнее

Comment: Всё нужное для вопроса должно быть в самом вопросе. Завтра ссылка протухнет - и вопрос будет бесполезен.

Comment: я не знаю ,как прикрепить файл с компьютера. Я могу только на сторонний файлообменник загрузить.

Comment: @jsknt02, а вы в таких ситуациях только пример показывайте, если у вас в файле строки имеют одинаковую структуру, то нет смысла весь файл прикладывать, а хватит несколько строк -- для примера. Дополнительно рекомендуется показать ожидаемый результат -- описание задачи это хорошее дело, а наглядный результат огромный плюс

Comment: gil9red, понял, учту. Добавил ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @jsknt02, добавляйте `@` перед ником, чтобы ваш комментарий дошел до адресата )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаете строки одну за другой (`for line in file`)

Если строка начинается с `'>'`, считаете проценты для того, что накопилось, потом обнуляете счетчики символов общий и побуквенные

Если нет - добавляете длину строки к общему счётчику, и `line.count('A')` к побуквенному

```
cl = 0
ca = 0
with open("d:/proteins2.fasta") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if cl:
                percent = 100 * ca / cl
                print(percent)
            cl = 0
            ca = 0
        else:
            cl += len(line)
            ca += line.count('A')
    if cl:
        percent = 100 * ca / cl
        print(percent)
```

Первые блоки дают такие результаты по 'А':

```
6.629834254143646
7.194244604316546
6.652360515021459
```

Comment: в  первой строке ,которая начинается с символа '>' не должны считаться символы. Например, в строке >sp...SV-2 или в строке >sp...SV-1 не должны считаться буквы

Comment: А я и не говорил, что в этой строке должны считаться символы - она только как триггер работает

Comment: @jsknt02 Вы вчера получили рабочий код. Что-то в нём было непонятно?

Comment: спасибо за помощь, извините, забыл выбрать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, нужно что-то вроде этого (если по-быстрому):

```
letters=['A','S']
linenum=0
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        linenum +=1
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            for _ in letters:
                print("line #{} - letter {} found {} times;".format(linenum, _, line.count(_)), end='')
            print("")
```

На выходе:

```
line #:2 - letter A found 9 times; line #:2 - letter S found 4 times
line #:3 - letter A found 4 times; line #:3 - letter S found 3 times
line #:4 - letter A found 5 times; line #:4 - letter S found 0 times
line #:6 - letter A found 6 times; line #:6 - letter S found 1 times
line #:7 - letter A found 7 times; line #:7 - letter S found 4 times
line #:8 - letter A found 5 times; line #:8 - letter S found 1 times
line #:9 - letter A found 2 times; line #:9 - letter S found 2 times
line #:10 - letter A found 5 times; line #:10 - letter S found 3 times
line #:11 - letter A found 1 times; line #:11 - letter S found 0 times
line #:13 - letter A found 8 times; line #:13 - letter S found 3 times
line #:14 - letter A found 2 times; line #:14 - letter S found 0 times
```

Если нужно с процентами, то так:

```
letters=['A','S']
linenum=0
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        linenum +=1
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            perc=[]
            print("line#{}".format(linenum), end='')
            for _ in letters:                
                print(" letter {} found {} times; ".format(_, line.count(_)), end='')
                perc.append(line.count(_))
            print("Percantage: {:.2f}%/{:.2f}%".format(perc[0]/sum(perc)*100, perc[1]/sum(perc)*100))
```

На выходе:

```
line#2 letter A found 9 times;  letter S found 4 times; Percantage: 69.23%/30.77%
line#3 letter A found 4 times;  letter S found 3 times; Percantage: 57.14%/42.86%
line#4 letter A found 5 times;  letter S found 0 times; Percantage: 100.00%/0.00%
line#6 letter A found 6 times;  letter S found 1 times; Percantage: 85.71%/14.29%
line#7 letter A found 7 times;  letter S found 4 times; Percantage: 63.64%/36.36%
line#8 letter A found 5 times;  letter S found 1 times; Percantage: 83.33%/16.67%
line#9 letter A found 2 times;  letter S found 2 times; Percantage: 50.00%/50.00%
line#10 letter A found 5 times;  letter S found 3 times; Percantage: 62.50%/37.50%
line#11 letter A found 1 times;  letter S found 0 times; Percantage: 100.00%/0.00%
line#13 letter A found 8 times;  letter S found 3 times; Percantage: 72.73%/27.27%
line#14 letter A found 2 times;  letter S found 0 times; Percantage: 100.00%/0.00%
```

Тут нюанс - форматированный вывод рассчитан на две буквы, так что, нужно будет подрихтовать, если что.